# Fixed Mega Menu - How to enable scroll on mobile without a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I am using this megamenu code:
https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MKXweV

But I have added

```
.menu-container{
    position:fixed;
}
```

This works for desktop versions, but when you shrink to mobile, it means that you can't see all the menu items. I can add

```
.menu-container{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

to the mobile styles to create a scroll bar, but I would prefer to not have a scrollbar, I just want the user to be able to scroll down to see all menu items the same way it works when the position is set to relative.

How can I achieve this effect without losing the fixed position on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually mobile devices don t show scroll bar. Only on dev mode you see scroll bars.
Change `overflow-y: scroll` to `auto;`

Or remove the scroll bar

```
.my-div-class::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 0; // Or display: none;
}
```

Note that this may not work in any browsers.
Target the div that you want no scrollbar

Comment: This still adds a scroll bar

Comment: actually mobile devices don t show scroll bar.
Only on dev mode you see scroll bars.